# MySQL: ORDER BY which uses own property or property of newest associated object

Tags: mysql, associations, sql-order-by

For the issue I ran into, the following database model is relevant: **A store has zero or more ratings. A rating has zero or more messages.** Meaning a rating has the foreign key store_id and a message has the foreign key rating_id.

We used to query all ratings first ordered by their status (read vs unread) and secondly ordered by their created timestamp:

```
// currenty query with simple order by
SELECT *
FROM rating rating
WHERE rating.store_id = $storeId
ORDER BY status DESC, created_timestamp DESC;
```

Now we want to take the messages of ratings into account. **ratings with messages should be ordered depending on the created_timestamp of the newest message** and depending on the status (read vs unread) of that message. And I want to select all ratings (with and without messages) in a single query.

It is hard for me to even abstract the problem to a well known problem set. Can somebody point me into the right direction?

---

**UPDATE**

With the help of Barmar I created the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM rating r
LEFT JOIN (SELECT m.rating_id, m.created_timestamp, m.status
           FROM messages m
           JOIN (SELECT rating_id, MAX(created_timestamp) maxtime
                 FROM messages
                 GROUP BY rating_id) mmax
           ON m.rating_id = mmax.rating_id AND m.created_timestamp = mmax.maxtime) m
ON m.rating_id = r.id
ORDER BY m.status DESC, m.created_timestamp DESC
```

However I have two problems with that solution:

1. It does not handle the case when the rating has no associated messages (in this case i want to have it orderey by the status and created_timestamp of the rating itself)
2. I do not understand why I need to do two joins to get the newest rating for each message

Comment: can you make some examples of what output are you getting and what would you like to get

Comment: As Output I just the ratings with all columns. I still want to get the ratings, but they should be orderey by their messages as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM rating r
LEFT JOIN (SELECT m.store_id, m.created_timestamp, m.status
           FROM messages m
           JOIN (SELECT store_id, MAX(created_timestamp) maxtime
                 FROM messages
                 GROUP BY store_id) mmax
           ON m.store_id = mmax.store_id AND m.created_timestamp = mmax.maxtime) m
ON m.store_id = r.store_id
ORDER BY m.status DESC, m.created_timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, but the message has a connection to a rating, so it has a rating_id but no store_id. I am not sure if this is just a type in your sql query of if I explained my problem the wrong way.

Comment: You didn't describe your schema at all in the question, so I just had to guess.

Comment: I said "A store has zero or more ratings. A rating has zero or more messages." but I guess I made it not clear enough. I will update it.

Comment: But you should get the general idea from my answer, it should be easy to adapt it to your particular schema.

Comment: I think you handled a different problem set because you assumed that message and rating both point to a store. To be honest I don't really  get the general idea from your solution.

Comment: You just need to change the joins to match your tables and foreign keys. Please give it a try, post your attempt, and then I'll help you if you can't get it working. We're not here to write your code for you, you're expected to understand the basics.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of some friends I actually found a working solution. It is totally different to the approach Barmar mentions, but it solves the exact problem:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (rating.status = "unread") 
THEN GREATEST(IFNULL(max(message.created_timestamp),0), rating.created_timestamp )
ELSE max(message.timestamp_ created) END
AS message_rating_timestamp_unread,
rating.status, rating.created_timestamp AS rating_created_timestamp
FROM rating
LEFT join message
ON message.rating_id =  rating.id
WHERE(message.status = "unread" OR message.status is NULL)
GROUP BY rating.id
ORDER BY message_rating_timestamp_unread DESC, rating_created_timestamp DESC;
```

Let me try to abstract the problem and guide you through the solution, so that it might help others. In my case the rating is the main object and the message is the associated object to a rating:

1. A LEFT JOIN to the associated object is obviously necessary. You need to test against the condition (in my case message.status = "unread"), but you also need to take into account that you might not find an appropriate association that fullfills the conditoin but still need your current column (in my case test against message.status is NULL)
2. Because of the LEFT JOIN you also need to GROUP BY the Primary Key of your main object, so that you don't get duplicates
3. You need to use GREATEST to get the highest value of the property of your main object and the associated object. Testing against IFNULL is also necessary if NULL values are in your data.

I will try to update my explanation, to make it more obvious. I hope the solution helps other people.